# Inverted Date on TDBGRID

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, tdbgrid

My TDBGrid is inverting my date, even if is a string.
Ive got this STRING on my database

> 01/06/2016 09:05

I just want it to show as string, not date
when I set it to TDBGrid the result is:

> 09:05 01/06/2016

My database is FoxPro .DBF, the data im asking for is **STRING**, *not* date
there is the code

```
procedure TfrmMensagensRecEnv.dbgRecebidasDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
  var sData, sHora, sTotal : String;
begin
  sHora  := Copy(MSGTBL.FieldByName('DATA_LIDA').AsString,12,20); (09:50:55)
  sData  := Copy(MSGTBL.FieldByName('DATA_LIDA').AsString,0,10); (01/06/2016)
  if Column.FieldName = 'DATA_LIDA' then
  begin
    sTotal := sData + ' ' + sHora;
    dbgRecebidas.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,Rect.Left+3,Rect.Top, sTotal);
  end;
end;
```

I upload a pic in TinyPic with SQL assistent im using showing my string data and the grid.
http://tinypic.com/r/2jameco/9

[image: DelphiImage]

Here is my .DFM grid code

```
object dbgRecebidas: TDBGrid
            Left = 2
            Top = 2
            Width = 774
            Height = 197
            DataSource = dtsMSGTBL
            DrawingStyle = gdsClassic
            FixedColor = 16771022
            GradientEndColor = 16771022
            Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
            Font.Color = clWindowText
            Font.Height = -11
            Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
            Font.Style = []
            Options = [dgTitles, dgIndicator, dgColumnResize, dgColLines, dgRowLines, dgCancelOnExit, dgTitleClick]
            ParentFont = False
            TabOrder = 0
            TitleFont.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
            TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
            TitleFont.Height = -11
            TitleFont.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
            TitleFont.Style = []
            OnCellClick = dbgRecebidasCellClick
            OnDrawColumnCell = dbgRecebidasDrawColumnCell
            OnDblClick = dbgRecebidasDblClick
            OnKeyPress = dbgRecebidasKeyPress
            Columns = <
              item
                Color = 15461355
                Expanded = False
                FieldName = 'COD_MSG'
                Title.Caption = 'Cod Msg'
                Title.Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
                Title.Font.Color = clWindowText
                Title.Font.Height = -11
                Title.Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
                Title.Font.Style = [fsBold]
                Width = 60
                Visible = True
              end
              item
                Color = 15461355
                Expanded = False
                FieldName = 'COD_TIP'
                Title.Caption = 'Tipo'
                Title.Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
                Title.Font.Color = clWindowText
                Title.Font.Height = -11
                Title.Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
                Title.Font.Style = [fsBold]
                Width = 56
                Visible = True
              end
              item
                Color = 15461355
                Expanded = False
                FieldName = 'COD_USU'
                Title.Caption = 'Usu'#225'rio'
                Title.Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
                Title.Font.Color = clWindowText
                Title.Font.Height = -11
                Title.Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
                Title.Font.Style = [fsBold]
                Visible = True
              end
              item
                Color = 15461355
                Expanded = False
                FieldName = 'TITULO'
                Title.Caption = 'T'#237'tulo'
                Title.Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
                Title.Font.Color = clWindowText
                Title.Font.Height = -11
                Title.Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
                Title.Font.Style = [fsBold]
                Width = 322
                Visible = True
              end
              item
                Color = 15461355
                Expanded = False
                FieldName = 'DATA_INCL'
                Title.Caption = 'Data de Inclus'#227'o'
                Title.Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
                Title.Font.Color = clWindowText
                Title.Font.Height = -11
                Title.Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
                Title.Font.Style = [fsBold]
                Width = 101
                Visible = True
              end
              item
                Color = 15461355
                Expanded = False
                FieldName = 'DATA_LIDA'
                Title.Caption = 'Data de Leitura'
                Title.Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
                Title.Font.Color = clWindowText
                Title.Font.Height = -11
                Title.Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
                Title.Font.Style = [fsBold]
                Width = 93
                Visible = True
              end
```

Comment: The DBGrid does not change the display of anything. If you want the date to display in a special format, set it using the field's `OnGetText` event using the `DisplayText` parameter.

Comment: A string is a string. It should display this string as-is in the database. If what you're saying is true, either you're using a third-party DBGrid, or you have some formatting settings which we cannot see.

Comment: @JerryDodge theres no formatting settings, Right now I tried get day, month and year separated and add as Day +'-'+Month+'-'+Year+ ' * ' Hour and it shows Hour * day-month-year hahah, its blowing my mind

Comment: Instead of showing single code lines without context, edit your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it is impossible to say where you are doing something wrong. Also edit your question with database type and field type you are using for your date-time string. The MCVE should ofcourse include how you post the date-time to, and how you retrieve it from the db.

Comment: @Tom, theres nothing more to add, its already on my question that it is a STRING and the get is already there too, its right on my database , but showing wrong on TDBGrid and its not single lines, its the full code theres only 4 line on DrawColumnCell action

Comment: Ok, since I have no idea what may be wrong, I'm out. Good luck

Comment: Oh yes, I read it. I even tried in a project I have open in front of me and I could not replcate your problem.

Comment: As I said, the DBGrid does **not** change the display of your data. It displays the data as defined by the field to which the column is connected. You're looking in the wrong place, but since you're not going to listen to what we have to say anyway, why bother? (I have considerable experience with DBGrids, such as the fact I have about 15 applications in daily use by 50 users where the main display of data is done in DBGrids; each application contains at least a dozen on various forms. The DBGrid does **NOT** change the format of the underlying data.)

Comment: @gui.ess:  It's a pity you are dismissing KenW and TomB's attempts to help without really engaging with what they are saying.  They are both frequent and very helpful contributors to answering Delphi qs at SO, and if you aren't going to listen to folks like them, there's hardly any point you posting on SO in the first place.

Comment: Btw, your code `Grid.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+3, Rect.Top, sData + ' ' + sTotal` seems wrong.  In the code you quote above it, `sTotal := sData + ' ' + sHour;`, `sTotal` already contains `sData`, so why are you passing `sData + ' ' + sTotal` to `TextRec`?

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, I tried your way but i didnt commented here, I wasnt trying to sound rude, I updated my post and added a pic, so you can see im not crazy

Comment: @MartynA Im sorry, Im having a sh** week and I said rude things to TomBrunberg. I've been trying this code for 2 days already, and my Grid.Canvas.... is ok, its working.

Comment: Try to write something like this: `ShortDateFormat := 'dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm';` in your code. The shortdateformat variable provides the short (compact) formatting used for default date to string conversion.
 
It is used by the DateToStr, DateTimeToStr and DateTimeToString routines

Comment: @ValMarinov, it's not entirely clear, but the Op seems to be saying that the date+time is being stored in a **string** field, so no date to string conversion should be involved?

Comment: @Martin This is exactly the idea of the experiment. To discover the type of field :)

Comment: Can you provide proof that the data type of this database field is in fact a `string`? And how about the column definition of the grid?

Comment: Thank you for editing and at least attempting an MCVE (I cancelled my DV), but we need to see also the `TDBGrid` settings from the `.dfm` and also the same for the data components you are using. You are aware that the `OnDrawColumnCell` event occurs for every cell in the grid, and therefore assigning `sHora` and `sData` outside of the `if` block is not a good idea. However it's not the reason for your problem. Please copy the requested blocks from the `.dfm` and paste as an edit into your question.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot, is the `OnDrawColumnCell` you have shown complete? I guess I mean, did you add it only to workaround your date-time string problem or does it have some other purpose?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I was using OnDrawColumnCell to TRY show it right, Im already using DataSource, but it was showing inverted, then I tried with variables on OnDrawColumnCell...but still wrong. here is a picture from my grid properties and my database properties, and I'll paste on my question, but I think i'll give up, I will create another column to show 'hour', so 2 column: 'Date' and 'Hour' :( thanks for trying help me guys

Comment: @JerryDodge http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/2wojgpu/9

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code of an entirely self-contained project which does **not**
exhibit the problem you describe.  The resulting display is

[image]
So, if you get a different result with your project, it is being caused by something you are not showing us in your code or DFM.

As you can see, the only difference between the display of the date + time is that for the TDateTime field, the seconds are included.

Btw, this I hope shows the value of preparing an MCVE as Tom Brunberg suggested you provide.

Code:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Field : TField;
begin
  Field:= TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'ID';
  Field.Name := Field.FieldName;
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  Field:= TStringField.Create(Self);
  Field.Size := 40;
  Field.FieldName := 'StringField';
  Field.Name := Field.FieldName;
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  Field:= TDateTimeField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'DateTimeField';
  Field.Name := Field.FieldName;
  Field.FieldKind := fkData;
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  CDS1.InsertRecord([1, '01/06/2016 09:05', '01/06/2016 09:05']);
end;
```

Comment: here is the properties window of dbg column http://tinypic.com/r/11lk5z7/9, theres apparentelly nothing wrong, and thanks for trying help me

Comment: Hmm, at the risk of stating the obvious, it's your app that needs debugging; we can't do that for you.  Create a new form containing a DBGrid with no defined columns ( so that the grid auto-creates them at run-time) and a TDBEdit connected to your field you are having problems with.  Does the grid show the same as the TDBEdit, and are thy now correct or still wrong?

Comment: @gui.ess As a conclusion (for my part) I have not found anything in the presented facts that would explain the result you see in the grid. There are some minor contradictions in the facts you have stated, probably not relevant to the issue. It is a pitty that you have neglected MartynA's suggestion of a simple test, I guess you run out of stamina. Anyway, since you also have not provided an MCVE there's really nothing more to do here.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to elaborate?  Questioners on SO are constantly being asked to provide an MCVE; the one is this case was asked but did not provide one.  I provided a self-contained MCVE to show that the display problem doesn't arise in it, and it's a bit exasperating to get a down-vote for my trouble!

Comment: I downvoted because the answer comes down to "You didn't provide an MCVE", which is not an answer. It's a reason to close.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: To my way of looking, the answer comes down to "Here is an MCVE which is entirely self-contained and doesn't exhibit your problem, so you (the OP) could perfectly well adapt what you're doing to follow it, if you make the effort".    That *is* an answer.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, I just disagree.

Comment: @MorganThrapp:  Ok, well thanks for explaining, anyway.